# amCharts dateAxis displays only time and not date

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

chart data date is the following example format: 
5/17/19 18:00

However, the chart only shows time on the date axis like:
18:00

I wish to be able to show the complete date with time, same as the way it is in the data object.

i tried setting input date format, and chart date format. didnt help.

here is the working code:
https://codepen.io/pthakkar/pen/dEzOJo

```
chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy H:mm";
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "M/dd/yy H:mm";
```

1. Hoping to show full date on chart.

Additional minor issues unable to fix:

2. Click and drag does not result into zoom, it only selects / highlights the area. Wish to achieve zoom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your charts `baseInterval` is `hour` so you should set the date format for `hour` key ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Formatting_date_and_time)):

```
categoryAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "M/dd/yy H:mm");
```

Maybe you want to set the format for other keys. Therefore take a look at the previously linked docs.

The `inputDateFormat` is only for reading the data.

For zooming you have set your cursor behavior to this:

```
chart.cursor.behavior = "selectX";
```

You should just remove that line or set it to `zoomX` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/#Cursor_behavior)):

```
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomX";
```

Alternatively you can use `zoomY` or `zoomXY`.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwJZYx) I forked your code pen and updated it.